# Why doesn't orleans doesn't show 'Hello World'?

Tags: orleans

I am following [Microsoft Orleans Tutotials](http://orleans.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=My%20First%20Orleans%20Application&referringTitle=Step-by-step%20Tutorials) to do the 'Hello World' and I was able to get everything compiled but when I run I get

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

instead of showing 'Hello World!'. I put a break point in the return statement from the Grain and it is called after the print actually happened. It seems the execution happens even before the real grain is called. I thought the call return is a promise and should execute like closure. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to get the result of the task.

Comment: Yes, Need Result at the end. Can you make it answer so I can mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the result of the task.